Different representations of the Yukawa interaction
during studying Yukawa sector of the SM, I got confused with different reps of the Yukawa interaction.
First, this is what I am familiar with(let me show only electron mass term):
$$y_e \bar{L}_e H e_R$$
where $y_e$ is coupling constant, $L_e$ is left-handed lepton doublet
$$L_e = (\nu_e, e)^T \quad \text{and}\quad \bar{L}_e = (\bar{\nu}_e, \bar{e}),$$
$H$ is Higgs doublet and $e_R$ is right-handed electron singlet (under $SU(2)_L$).
Another representation is given as
$$y_e H L_e \bar{e}_e.$$
With ordinary matrix multiplication approach I can't get right answer. It seems each term is given as above but how can I compute explicitly it to get the right answer?

Your second form is wrong. Why didn’t you conjugate the Higgs doubles?

@CosmasZachos You mean $H^{\dagger}$? That makes sense for me though

Your second expression is meaningless. You need to saturate a row vector with a column vector, not to mention the spinor implicit index saturation, so it should be, instead,
$$y_e \bar{e}_R H^\dagger L_e .$$
Note now matrix multiplication dots the column 2-vector (spinor) on the row such, to produce an SU(2) invariant, as before.
